# C# TransactionScope - Unable to open connection randomly

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2012, ibatis, transactionscope

We have a handy delegate function which allows us to wrap up multiple calls to be included inside of the same transaction.

```
protected delegate object DatabaseFunctions();

protected object ExecuteInTransaction(DatabaseFunctions databaseFunctions)
{
    TransactionScope scope = null;
    if(!TransactionScope.IsInTransaction)
        scope = new TransactionScope();

    try
    {
        Object obj = databaseFunctions();
        if (scope != null)
            scope.Complete();
         return obj;
    }
......
```

We utilize this method on self hosted WCF endpoints, inside of our base library in WebAPI and within multi-threaded windows services.

We are experiencing an increase in the error below. This used to never happen and now when it does happen ( 3~4 times per week ) it is thrown by more than one thread. I have a theory that this is NOT happening within the self hosted WCF service ... perhaps because the calls there have instance resources of PER CALL set. But this hasn't been 100% confirmed yet.

1) What exactly is the problem here...is the provider having a hard time opening a connection to SQL Server OR is it actually having a hard time starting a transaction? And is this really a timeout?

2) Can this be MSDTC related? Normally I would see MSDTC errors if this were actually the issue...there is nothing that I have seen but can't tell if the stack trace indicates that MSDTC is being used.

3) Our "load" on the system has certainly gone way up just before the problem began.

Error in ExecuteInTransaction IBatisNet.DataMapper.Exceptions.DataMapperException: Unable to open connection to "Microsoft SQL Server, provider V4.0.0.0 in framework .NET V4.0". ---> System.Transactions.TransactionException: The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction. ---> System.TimeoutException: Transaction Timeout
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(InternalTransaction tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction atomicTransaction)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.Activate(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.PrepareConnection(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionInternal obj, Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.SqlMapSession.OpenConnection(String connectionString)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.SqlMapSession.OpenConnection(String connectionString)
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.SqlMapSession.OpenConnection()
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Commands.DbCommandDecorator.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.MappedStatements.MappedStatement.ExecuteInsert(ISqlMapSession session, Object parameterObject)
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.SqlMapper.Insert(String statementName, Object parameterObject)

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: I can't find `TransactionScope.IsInTransaction` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), is that something custom?  If I had to guess at the problem, I'd start looking at threading issues.

Comment: Good point! I had forgotten that isn't the native implementation.
http://ibatis.apache.org/SDK/dotnet/IBatisNet.Common.Transaction.TransactionScopeMembers.html

I agree it's likely a threading issue, we are going to create some load tests to try to reproduce. But I still have the question of what exactly the error is...it's confusing that the stack trace says it can't open the connection but also that the state is wrong.